# HTTP Authentication fails from PHP script on Wowza Server?

Tags: php, http-authentication, wowza

Is there a configuration/setting for the Wowza server that must be correct to allow HTTP Authentication?

According to [How to get realtime connection counts from Wowza Media Server](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?129-Built-in-HTTProviders-that-Provide-Server-Stats), I should be able to get some XML information that I need.  If I go to the url from a browser, it prompts for username/password, and I get the data, but if I try to accomplish it from PHP it fails no matter what method I use:

```
HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
```

**Method #1:**

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://admin:password@123.123.123.123:8086/connectioncounts');
```

**Method #2**:

```
$handle = fopen('http://admin:password@123.123.123.123:8086/connectioncounts', "r")
```

**Method #3**:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, http://123.123.123.123:8086/connectioncounts);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "admin:password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Check firewall setting if 8086 port is open.

Comment: Probably you are connecting to wrong server or supplying wrong credentials? Also check this post on proper way of doing http_auth with file_get_contents. http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-file-get-contents-sending-username-password/

Comment: Thanks your question helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try change CURLAUTH_BASIC to CURLAUTH_ANY

Comment: Thanks for ur help. May you explain what is the difference?